# IPV6 extension header length

Tags: ip, ipv6

I want to parse a IPV6 packet that consists of extension headers. The "Hdr Ext Len" (second) field of extension headers such as Hop by Hop option, Routing, destination options and Authentication header, is defined as

> 8-bit unsigned integer. Length of the header in 8-octet units, not including the first 8 octets.

Consider the following IPV6 packet with authentication header (AH). The second byte of AH has a value 04 which signifies 24 bytes (got this information from hex packet decoder in https://hpd.gasmi.net/).
I would like to know how to decode the value of this field "Hdr Ext Len" to get the actual extension header size.

IPV6 Header

6E 00 00 00 00 34 33 01 FE 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 FE 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01

Authentication extension header

59 **04** 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 15 8F 74 57 E3 C2 D4 13 EF 5E F1 FF 13

OSPF packet

03 02 00 1C 02 02 02 02 00 00 00 01 E9 DF 00 00 00 00 00 13 05 DC 00 01 00 00 0B 93

Comment: The AH is different in that the length is calculated differently. _[RFC 4302, IP Authentication Header](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4302.txt)_ explains it in Section 2.2, Payload Length. It must be a multiple of eight octets.

Comment: Read the link Ron provided. The AH header specifies the length in multiples of 32-bit, so in multiples of 4 octets. Minus 2. So 4+2=6, 6x4 octets=24 octets.

Comment: Thanks. So how about for other headers such as hop-by-hop, routing, destination options. Will it be 8 x "Hdr Ext Len" + 8?